# B 'isA' A. What is the opposite relationship called in Java?

Tags: java

If, in Java, B extends A. We would say B 'is-A' A. What is the opposite directions relationship called? A 'insert' B?

Comment: A ***might-be-a*** B ?

Comment: A **is-a-superclass-of** B.   Or A **is-inherited-by** B if you don't mind passive voice.

Comment: @YassinHajaj that implies that in general A **isnt-a** B. ;-)  (Otherwise known as the *You Can't Get There From Here* principle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's substitute `A` as `Animal`, `B` as `Cat`. If `Cat` extends `Animal` ,`Cat` is a subclass of `Animal` or `Cat` is-a(n) `Animal`. Opposite direction relationship can be called as `Animal` is a super class of `Cat`

Comment: Ok, so saying that Animal has a cat would be absolutely wrong?

Comment: Yes it would be absolutely wrong.   (Does it make any sense to say that an animal "has" a cat ... in English?)

Answer (score 0):

We would say that B inherits A.

Comment: Or maybe that "A is a super class of B."

Comment: Actually it is B that is doing the inheriting; A is merely _inherited from_.

Comment: Thank you - I conflated the two in my head.

Answer (score 0):

All B’s are A’s but not all A’s are B’s

For example if you define an Animal class and a Shape class then both animal and shape instances are objects but an instance of each do not extend/implement each other, therefor having no direct relationship.

So a shape is not an animal and an animal is not a shape but both animal and shape extend and therefor are objects